# Log in firebase in codeanywhere or upload webapp files in firebase without cli

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli, codeanywhere

I have a webapp firebase project in codeanywhere but I can't login in firebase, I have installed firebase-tools@9.23.3 and when I run "firebase login --no-localhost" I have a link to log in, but when I click on link another page is opened with:

> "Errore 400: invalid_request The version of the app you're using
> doesn't include the latest security features to keep you protected.
> Please make sure to download from a trusted source and update to the
> latest, most secure version."

I wrote to support of codeanywhere and they said that don't officially support firebase. So I want to know if there is a workaround to deploy the webapp in firebase inside codeanywhere or eventually upload the webapp files in firebase without cli.
Basically I would not like to install any editor and any cli on my pc and be able to work only online on my firebase project. I can also use another environment like codeanywhere as long as it allows me to work (edit and deploy) only online to my firebase project.

Update:

```
cabox@nodejs-white-lion:~/workspace/GAU$ sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'npm' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
After this operation, 125 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 40238 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nodejs (14.21.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
cabox@nodejs-white-lion:~/workspace/GAU$ curl -sL deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 16.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease [22.2 kB]
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x xenial InRelease        
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease  
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease    
Fetched 22.2 kB in 0s (36.5 kB/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

## Confirming "xenial" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x/dists/xenial/Release'

## Adding the NodeSource signing key to your keyring...

+ curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg >/dev/null

## Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js 16.x repo...

+ echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x xenial main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
+ echo 'deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x xenial main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

## Running `apt-get update` for you...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease [22.2 kB]
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease  
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease    
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x xenial InRelease [4,584 B]
Get:8 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x xenial/main amd64 Packages [774 B]
Fetched 27.6 kB in 0s (28.2 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 16.x and npm
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null
     echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn


cabox@nodejs-white-lion:~/workspace/GAU$ udo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
bash: udo: command not found
cabox@nodejs-white-lion:~/workspace/GAU$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease [22.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease    
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x xenial InRelease        
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease  
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Fetched 22.2 kB in 0s (41.8 kB/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package yarn
cabox@nodejs-white-lion:~/workspace/GAU$ node -v
v14.16.0
cabox@nodejs-white-lion:~/workspace/GAU$
```

Comment: The latest version is `11.16.0`. Have you tried installing it? `npm i firebase-tools@11.16.0`

Comment: I tried "npm -g install firebase-tools@11.16.0" and then "firebase login --no-localhost" and I have "Firebase CLI v11.16.0 is incompatible with Node.js v14.16.0 Please upgrade Node.js to version ^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0"

Comment: Can you [update Node JS version](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195570/1090153) in that case if feasible?

Comment: When I tried "sudo apt-get upgrade" it ask me which MySQL product I wish to configure. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I posted what I have done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249431/discussion-between-asv-and-dharmaraj).